# Cross-parameter constraint for functions with parameters having different ordering in each function

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

So I have a problem statement in which I want to have a validation to take place on the inputs of a function and the validation has to take place using two of the inputs provided in the function but the functions on which I have to do these they have their inputs in varied orders. So I have to run validation using two variables suppose a and b. But the functions on which I have to run the validation have their function definition as

1. f1(a, b, c)
2. f2(a, d, b)
3. f3(a, c, d, b)

Also I am not able to use instanceof as the instance of b collides with d. So there any other way in which this can be done?

Comment: Validation based on the names of the function arguments?

Comment: 1. can each function f1,f2,f3 have its own validation since they know their parameters?  2. can you pass parameters for validation as array like `Object... params` and then do your validation based on size of params array? 3. as @onnoweb said, can you have additional parameter like `functionName` to distinguish how to validate parameters?

Comment: So the I was planning on using something like this http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/cross-parameter-constraints/ for validation. So there I receive the array of Objects as an input which are the Objects which are parameters of the function. What I wanted to know was if I can get the parameter only a and b from the Object list.